# App Android somente para tablets

Tags: android, google-play

Desenvolvi uma aplicação android usando o [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), nos arquivos `xml` das telas eu usei o layout do [Nexus 10](https://www.google.com/nexus/10/) pois minha aplicação é somente para tablets.

Depois que subi a aplicação pra loja do [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store) vi que tinham `4194` dispositivos habilitados a usarem minha aplicação, ou seja, smartphones e tablets.

Como faço para limitar esses dispositivos somente para tablets?

Comment: Você quer *evitar* ou *proibir* o uso em celulares?

Comment: @utluiz quero proibir, pois não sei qual será o comportamento do app em telas menores.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você pode ativar/desativar os tipos de telas disponíveis atualizando a entrada support-screens do seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

#### [Fonte](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Você ainda pode encontrar uma sessão completa da documentação sobre o suporte a diferentes telas [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: É isto mesmo @hernandes! Coloquei esse código no `manifest` e subi um novo apk pra loja, agora apareceu somente `711` dispositivos.

Answer (score 8):

Segundo [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092101/android-restricting-apk-install-for-small-screens) a configuração do *manitest*, conforme mencionada na resposta do @hernandes,  impede os usuários de encontrar seu aplicativo no *market place*, mas se eles tiverem o arquivo `apk` em mãos eles não serão impedidos de instalar o mesmo.

Uma proteção adicional consistiria em verificar a resolução da tela na inicialização do aplicativo e, caso não seja adequada, emitir um aviso de "tamanho de tela não suportado" e finalizar a aplicação.

Segue um exemplo de código para recuperar os valores programaticamente extraído [deste outro tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465680/how-to-determine-the-screen-width-in-terms-of-dp-or-dip-at-runtime-in-android):

```java
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

Comment: Não sabia desta possibilidade @utluiz, vou adicionar no meu código e testar, vlw.