# Critério utilizados pelo Google Play para determinar se um aplicativo é projetado para tablets

Tags: android, google-play

Tenho um aplicativo feito para Android, e tomei todo cuidado possível com relação a layout, resoluções de tela, dpi etc. Inclusive, tudo está devidamente configurado no manifesto.

O layout da aplicação é bem diferente em um celular e em tablets.

Ainda assim o Google insiste que:

...seu APK não parece ter sido projetado para tablets de 7"

...seu APK não parece ter sido projetado para tablets de 10"

Dizendo que eu devo seguir essa regra aqui: [Take advantage of extra screen area available on tablets](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#use-extra-space)

Cheguei a assumir que "o robô" que faz essa análise dá esse resultado por não encontrar todos os arquivos XML de layout em pastas distintas, como

- layout
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp
- etc

Contudo, apesar de eu não ter criado essas pastas, eu trato todos os casos de layout e orientação via código, alterando seus elementos e espaçamento conforme necessário.

---

Depois de quase dois meses de pesquisa (de 24/4 até 19/6), ainda não consegui determinar exatamente o que "o robô" procura, então entrei em contato diretamente com o pessoal do Google para que eles fizessem uma revisão manual do meu app, através do link [Designed for Tablets Contact Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq) na página [Tablet App Quality](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html).

Eles me responderam da seguinte forma:

> Thank you for contacting Google Play Support. Upon further review, we have determined that your application, br.com.carlosrafaelgn.fplay, does not meet the basic tablet app quality checklist to be considered designed for use on tablet devices as explained here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html. Kindly visit this link and concentrate your efforts on the following:
>
> 2 - Optimize your layouts for larger screens
>
> 3 - Take advantage of extra screen area available on tablets
>
> 4 - Use Icons and other assets that are designed for tablets screens
>
> 11 - Showcase your tablet UI in Google Play

O que me deixou mais confuso, afinal, [meu app](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid) usa pouquíssimos drawables (quase todos os ícones do [app](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid) são provenientes de uma fonte customizada, de modo que cada ícone é um glyph da fonte, podendo ser facilmente redimensionado para qualquer tamanho). E todos os ícones provenientes de drawables possuem versões MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI e XXHDPI.

Minha confusão vem do número 4:

> Use Icons and other assets that are designed for tablets screens

Alguém já passou por isso, e tem a mínima ideia do que isso significa (já que eu criei as 4 versões de drawables)?

Quais são os critérios que ele, o robo do Google Play, utiliza para determinar se um APK não é projetado para tablets?

Comment: Meu palpite é que ele use como critério a presença de arquivos de layout em pastas distintas mesmo, porque analisar o código compilado ficaria meio complicado com o uso de obfuscadores de código como ProGuard por exemplo. Fico um pouco surpreso de saber que você teve mais facilidade customizando isso programaticamente do que através dos XML. Foi isso mesmo?

Comment: Foi sim! No meu caso compensava mudar o layout via código. Percebi que a maioria das mudanças consistiam em espaçamento alterado e tamanho de fonte. As mudanças mais brutais estão na activity Main, e para ela eu efetivamente criei uma pasta layout-sw600dp.

Comment: Achei muito desperdício simplesmente copiar os outros arquivos para dentro do layout-sw600dp e aumentar o tamanho do APK sem necessidade.

Comment: Entendi. Não conheço uma alternativa para tamanho de fonte, mas para espaçamentos eu teria parametrizado o valor de cada dimensão em arquivos `dimens.xml` customizados para cada perfil de aparelho, um padrão em `res/values/dimens.xml`, outro em `res/values-land/dimens.xml`, `res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml`, etc. Entendeu a idéia? Os valores guardados em `dimens.xml` são definidos em `dp` (ou `dip`, como preferir).

Comment: Concordo. Mas será que isso seria o suficiente para o Google Play entender? Se for, mudo agora :) Eu gostaria muito de ter uma lista com os itens que eles verificam...

Comment: Acredito que sim, pois é a única maneira que vejo para o Google definir quais perfis de aparelho um aplicativo aceita.

Comment: Complementando: sobre os critérios, vale a pena ler esse item da documentação, que diz que você pode ter que declarar especificamente tamanhos large e extra-large de telas no Manifest dependendo da versão de Android que seu aplicativo suporta: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#support-screens

Comment: Pois é, já conhecia essas regras, e isso está devidamente declarado no manifesto. Aliás, foi por causa disso que me espantei inicialmente com o que o Google Play acusou. Esse aqui é o manifesto da minha aplicação [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Talvez [essa minha pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1911/app-android-somente-para-tablets) te ajude em algo, pode ser que adicionar o `support-screens` no manifest e habilitar tudo funcione.

Comment: Oi @iTSangar, isso já foi feito e sem sucesso. Dê uma olhada no meu manifesto aqui [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Olhando o seu Manifest e vendo tudo o que você fez, parece estar correto. Porém olhando as recomendações no site, não sei se você adicionou screen-shots para tablets de 7" e 10" que é recomendado no item 11.

Além disso, acho que não é necessário ter as pastas de sw600dp e sw720dp, tendo as padrões (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi e xxhdpi) basta. Foi isso que fiz num app que publiquei na play com suporte para tablets.

Comment: Adicionei os screenshots, aliás, foi por causa deles que recebi um erro do play "você submeteu capturas para tablets, mas seu aplicativo não parece ter sido projetado para tablets". Pois é, pra mim também não faz sentido **ter** que criar as pastas sw600dp e sw720dp, pois senão, como ficariam os jogos fullscreen, que só têm uma Activity...

Comment: Seu app ja esta em produção? Poderia disponibilizar o link do play? Outra dúvida, quando o google diz que não é compatível, é naquela aba de "optimization tips" não?

Comment: Sim! É open source, e já está no ar aqui: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.carlosrafaelgn.fplay Isso! É nos optimization tips...

Comment: Apesar do google falar que não é compatível com tablet, pude instalar no meu sem problemas.Para tentar ajudar segue a estrutura de pastas do meu projeto (http://postimg.org/image/ez5dld95l) e do layout para large screen que uso, ele tem dois fragments (não sei se a análise do google chega a verificar esse tipo de coisa, http://postimg.org/image/4kxtbwac5).
Outra coisa, no seu projeto notei o sufixo _l para layout large, não é melhor jogar para a pasta (layout-large) pra não precisar fazer a lógica no código? Não sei se influência na análise, mas reduz a probabilidade de erro no seu código.

Comment: Pois é, tenho dois tablets para testar, além do emulador. E instala e roda ok... Só o _l que não é para large, mas para landscape (w > h). Vou olhar sua estrutura assim que chegar ao PC.