# Meu App não aparece no Google Play em tablets

Tags: android, google-play

Desenvolvi um aplicativo, depois de pronto publiquei no ***Google Play***, acessei pelo celular e instalou corretamente.
Porém, quando acesso pelo tablet, o aplicativo não aparece listado, se acesso pelo PC, aparece a mensagem que não é compatível.

O app requer **Android 3.0** ou superior, testei com um *tablet Samsung de 10'* com **Android 4.2.2** e num *Multilaser de 7'* com **Android 4.4.2**. Nesse *tablet Samsung*, instalei e testei o aplicativo várias vezes pelo cabo, e não tive nenhum problema.

Trabalhei todo o *layout* para funcionar bem nas várias telas, criando arquivos para tamanhos, ajustando as imagens nas pastas e tudo mais.

Pesquisei na *Internet*, mas tem muita pouca coisa sobre o assunto. Achei este [post](http://www.hasmukhbhadani.com/2013/01/how-to-create-application-for-both.html) e implementei o que foi sugerido, não deu resultado.
O ***Google Play*** ainda me deu um aviso que a nova versão do meu app era compatível com menos aparelhos que a anterior.

Em resposta aos comentários:
Sim, marquei a opção para disponibilizar para tablets. Quanto as sugestões deste link de outra pergunta, já havia visto antes e já fiz tudo que diz lá. Também coloquei os screenshots de telas de 7' e 10' no Google Play. Bem, eu uso o Android Studio e segue abaixo o meu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- xlarge screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

</compatible-screens>

<permission
    android:name="br.com.ingainformatica.servicos.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.ingainformatica.servicos.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SemConexaoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sem_conexao"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InicioActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inicio" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CadastroContribuinteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cadastro_pessoa_fisica" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LicitacaoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_licitacao" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LegislacaoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legislacao" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EsqueciMinhaSenhaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_esqueci_minha_senha" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProtocoloActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_protocolo" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProtocoloVisualizaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_protocolo_visualiza" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProtocoloCadastroActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_protocolo_cadastro" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LegislacaoListaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legislacao_lista" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LegislacaoVisualizaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legislacao_visualiza" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaVisualizaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_visualiza" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaCadastroActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_cadastro" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaCadastroFotoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_cadastro_foto" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaCadastroMapaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_cadastro_mapa" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC0XbnZq7nhfbchf95dO7ffmTU8sJHC2SQ" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DiarioActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_diario" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DiarioListaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_diario_lista" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaVisualizaMapaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_visualiza_mapa" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LicitacaoVisualizaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_licitacao_visualiza" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LicitacaoListaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_licitacao_lista" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LicitacaoLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_licitacao_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LicitacaoEsqueciSenhaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_licitacao_esqueci_senha" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OuvidoriaVisualizaGaleriaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ouvidoria_visualiza_galeria" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Verifique se marcou para disponibilizar para tablet na hora do desenvolvimento e publicação, nao lembro bem mas creio que há algum lugar que ele pergunta se voce deseja .... usou Android Studio ou outra IDE ?

Comment: Recomendo dar uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13906/crit%C3%A9rio-utilizados-pelo-google-play-para-determinar-se-um-aplicativo-%C3%A9-projetad/14709#14709, pode ter alguns detalhes que não viu.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique isso no seu APK, em Dicas de otimização do seu aplicativo, no Console do desenvolvedor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifique isso também:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cícero, em Dicas de Otimização, tenho apenas a mensagem "Você está indo bem Não temos dicas de otimização para você no momento." Nos prints tb não aparece mensagem nenhuma...
Por isso a estranheza, no console tudo indica que meu app é adequado para tablets...

Comment: :(  Bom, eu descobri que no meu caso, meu app parou de ser exibido para usuários com Tablets quando liberei um recurso que utiliza SMS. Aí tive que colocar aquela tag de user-freature de telefony para required=false. Funcionou!

Comment: Li isso tb, mas o meu não utiliza nenhum recurso de SMS, notificação ou ligações, apenas geolocalização e mapas, e coloquei o required=false em todos os meus user-feature...
Tô ficando sem opção e nada acontece. Mas obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar as outras densidades de tela:

```
<!-- large screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
<!-- xlarge screens -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
```