# Alguns aparelhos não encontram meu app na playstore

Tags: android

De um tempo pra ca que venho atualizando o aplicativo, alguns aparelhos nao encontram, tentei no meu tablet positivo de 10 polegadas, e não encontrou. ja configurei o manifest pra receber os suporte a telas de varios tipos, e nao encontra.
o targetVersion ta em 14, alguem sabe o que pode ser?

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

      <supports-screens 
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" 
            android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconefinal"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.Splash"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.SegmentoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.DescontoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.UtilView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ServicoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.EmpresaView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ViewWeb" 
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.MenuActivity"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ContatoWebView"
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RedeSocialView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

                <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RegiaoView" 
                     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    />
             />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Vejam como aparece na playstore:

"Seu APK em produção deve atender aos seguintes critérios:
Seu APK deve exigir somente recursos de hardware que normalmente estão disponíveis em tablets. Saiba mais
Faça upload de capturas de tela de tablet.
Faça upload de pelo menos uma captura de tela para tablets de 10" para a listagem da loja. Saiba mais."
Porem eu tenho 2 app publicado com esses avisos, que acham normalmente em qualquer dispositivo.

Comment: sinto muito mas sem código não temos como descobrir o problema, afinal só todos virarem adivinhos (desculpe a brincadeira.. viu?)... Edite a questão e coloque o "manifest".

Comment: Chegou a colocar imagens para dispositivos de 7" e 10" no **Store Listing**? Em caso afirmativo, elas estão com muito espaço em branco? Chegou a ter o mesmo problema que essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39028/meu-app-n%C3%A3o-aparece-no-google-play-em-tablets?

Comment: @WarLock, use o `@username` quando você quiser responder a alguma pessoa, se não não chega na minha inbox, eu nem lembrava mais da sua questão... Poste o manifest INTEIRO por favor.

Comment: @Wakim nao coloquei imagens de 7 e 10 nãom o problema é exatamente o mesmo, porem em dicas de otimização aparece la q o app nao foi projetado pra tablets,mas ja marquei la. ja postei o manifest.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento postado.

Comment: Existe uma marcação errada no seu XML, veja:             `<activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RegiaoView" 
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                />
         /></application>` isto está sobrando `/>`, o correto seria isto: `<activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RegiaoView" 
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                />
         </application>`

Comment: voce acha que pode ser isso?

Comment: Teste, se for isto me confirme para eu poder "oficializar" como resposta

Comment: Uses sdk limita as versões de android abrangidas pela sua aplicação.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: @WarLock editei a resposta. Poderia testar sem o `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`?

Answer (score 4):

Existem dois problemas no seu XML

1. Erro no xml

   ```
   <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RedeSocialView" 
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       />

           <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RegiaoView" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
               />
        /> <========= este fechamento de tag está errado, pois já existe um na linha de cima
   ```
2. Permissão solicitada que não existe em tablets:

   Você adicionou uma solicitação de permissão que não existe em tables, nesta linha

   Esta permissão é requerida, portanto a maioria dos tablets não serão listados, pois eles não tem suporte para ligações, você necessita definir o hardware (feature) de ligações como opcional, para fazer isto será necessário adicionar isto ao XML:

   A ausência `<uses-feature ..>` provavelmente é assumida como `<uses-feature android:required="true" ...>` pelos filtros da PlayStore, assim será obrigatório ter suporte para chamadas e tablets não tem tal suporte (na maioria dos casos).

O XML deve ficar assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

      <supports-screens 
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" 
            android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconefinal"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.Splash"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.SegmentoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.DescontoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.UtilView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ServicoView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.EmpresaView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ViewWeb" 
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.MenuActivity"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.ContatoWebView"
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
             />

        <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RedeSocialView" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />

                <activity android:name="br.com.insideweb.multpesquisa.view.RegiaoView" 
                     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                     />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Se ainda falhar recomendo que tente remover isto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Pois se tratando de tablets, isto não é algo necessário.

Comment: Olá fiz as alterações a msg sumiu la em otimizaçoes, mas o problema continua, meu tablet de 10 nao acha meu app

Comment: @WarLock seu app já foi aprovado?

Comment: eu publiquei faz quase 2h e meia, minhas atualizaçoes sempre ficam disponiveis em menos de 1h.

Comment: Publicado eu entendi, eu queria mesmo sabe se ele foi *aprovado*, qual o nome dele?

Comment: multpesquisa...

Comment: ja foi aprovado sim.

Comment: @WarLock to tentando testar aqui... Internet devegar

Comment: @WarLock Consegui abrir, mas emite a mensagem que o meu dispositivo não é compatível, por favor tente adicionar isto e me avise: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />`

Comment: Ja alterei, mas continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: @WarLock última tentativa sobre os features, teste todas por favor: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>` só pra teste.

Comment: continua sem encontrar.

Comment: @WarLock acho que descobri, remove "<supports-screens ...>" se você quiser que o aplicativo apareça para todas resoluções, me avise se der certo

Comment: mas deixa todos os features?

Comment: @WarLock não deixa como o XML que postei na resposta, mas só remove o supports-screen

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19991/discussion-between-war-lock-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Remova o supports-screens completamente (se suporta todas, para que listar?) e a  permissão CALL_PHONE, porque naturalmente um tablet não pode fazer ligações telefônicas. Se o seu aplicativo precisa disso, então só vai funcionar mesmo em telefones.

Comment: @epx acho que 'e isto mesmo, vou editar a respota :)