# Dispositivo incompatível com app da Play Store

Tags: java, android, google-play

Alguns dispositivos, especialmente um tablet não está conseguindo fazer o download de um aplicativo da play store. Alguem sabe dizer o que pode estar bloqueando?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icone"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas.PortalAluno"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas.sem_conexao" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <service android:label="BackgroundService" android:name="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas.BackgroundService"></service>
        <receiver android:name="com.sponte.PortalDeNotas.onBoot">
             <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
        </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>  
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Está tendo algum problema no Android Studio? Dê uma lida nisto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101703/101

Answer (score 1):

Você usou:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

O `android:minSdkVersion=14` faz requerer o Android 4.0, se o smartphone ou tablet não usar um android inferior então não poderá instalar o App.

Acredito que estes dois não interfiram:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Pois é apenas pedido de permissão e não uma `<uses-feature ..>`

Pergunta relacionada: [Alguns aparelhos não encontram meu app na playstore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45716/3635)

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela sua resposta. Porém o tablet em questão está com Android 4.4. Parece ser algo com o dispositivo mesmo. Estranho.

Comment: @BrunoViganó existe a necessidade de usar `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>` e
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`? Se não tiver experimente tirar, também experimente tirar o `android:allowBackup="true"`.