# Como publicar aplicativos para tablets na Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

Não consigo disponibilizar meu aplicativo para **tablets de 7 e 10 polegadas**, quando envio o APK no Developer Console, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

---

**Projete seu app para tablets**
Seu APK não parece ter sido projetado para tablets

---

Pesquisei sobre como resolver na internet mas não achei uma resposta para minha duvida. Este link foi o mais próximo que encontrei do meu problema.

[Critério utilizados pelo Google Play para determinar se um aplicativo é projetado para tablets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13906/crit%C3%A9rio-utilizados-pelo-google-play-para-determinar-se-um-aplicativo-%C3%A9-projetad)

Como mostra a imagem, fiz o layout para todos tamanhos e os icones tambem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma conferida, se você usa alguma permissão específica só pra smartphones, como por exemplo a de ligação:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Pra que funcione nos tablets também, vc deve alterar essa permissão, para:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Esse é só um exemplo, existem várias permissões que se vc usar no seu projeto, vai torná-lo exclusivo para smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas uma adição:
Criar Layouts para a menor largura como 600dp seria encorajado já que você planeja publicar para tablets. (layout-sw600dp)
xxhdpi às vezes ficam desconfortáveis em tablets de 10"